# Does Calling the Method HEAD on Azure CDN cache the actual resource too?

Tags: azure-cdn

I would like to pre cache my images on Azure CDN so I can have the original image resized ahead of time. So, I was thinking I could just call the HTTP method `HEAD` instead of `GET` to cache the image. But then I was thinking, when I do that am I just caching the HTTP response headers or am I also caching the actual resized image also? I'm really not sure how to go into the CDN and check if the image was actually cached.

Answer (score 0):

Why not actually try that out in a small experiment? If you perform a `HEAD` request and see something triggered on your server (for example, either look in your webserver's log file or call some script or application that is able to write a custom log file), then the resource was properly requested. If you perform an additional `GET` request on that resource, see it delivered through the CDN while no additional request can be monitored on your server (through the same mechanics that logged the first call), everything went fine.

To be sure, why not actually perform a proper `GET` request? Are you afraid to trigger service limits through that?

Comment: The main reason I don't try it out is that I don't have the CDN access in a feature environment or on my computer, I don't think I could run the CDN on my computer :-). The main reason I was wondering is because I thought it would be more efficient to use the HTTP method `HEAD` when I am calling a bunch of images at once. Maybe I'm doing some pre optimization that I shouldn't worry about :-/.